# Keyboard key issue in iOS11 in iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, ios11

My question is about keyboard key issue in iOS11 in iPhone 6. In keyboard key Y and Z is replaced. SS1: http://prntscr.com/glitvz and SS2: http://prntscr.com/gliudv. 
Please let me know if there is any workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this under Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards > [YourLanguage] > QWERTY instead of QWERTZ.

Also you could try to add another keyboard language as a workaround since i am a little concerned about the iOS 11 vKeyboard implementation.